# Install Ubuntu directly off a hard drive and dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a hard drive from the hard drive. I already have Windows 10 on it. My pc has no disk drive, and I have no flash drives. Can I install from the hard drive to another partition on that drive?

Comment: No, you can't (with only Windows, that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to install Ubuntu onto the same drive as you booted from, a bit complicated, yet possible. But it makes things much more complicated, that you have Windows on that drive, and I guess you want to keep it there.

I would really recommend, that you get (buy or borrow) a cheap USB flash drive (a 4 GB USB2 drive will do). See this link and links from it,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot install Ubuntu in the same hard disk unless you have some external storage device(flash drive, CD/DVD, External hard drive) because you need an external bootable media which should contain the files required to install Ubuntu.